# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I am trying to a create a basic Ionic web application by following [these video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O41ssU5nTZE&list=PLYxzS__5yYQng-XnJhB21Jc7NW1OIaqct&index=12&pbjreload=10).

I am getting a `TypeError` on the following statement:

```
console.log('would login user with ', this.user.value, this.password.value)
```

The error message is

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Here is my full `login.ts` code, which should sign in with the registered mail id and password through Firebase:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

/**
* Generated class for the LoginPage page.
*
* See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
* Ionic pages and navigation.
*/

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-login',
templateUrl: 'login.html',
})

export class LoginPage {

@ViewChild('username') user;
@ViewChild('password') password;

constructor(private fire: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
}

signInUser() {
**console.log('would login user with ', this.user.value, this.password.value);**
//this line is giving error.
this.fire.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.value, this.password.value)


}
}
```

login.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Login
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

<ion-list>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<div padding>
    <button block ion-button (click)="signInUser()">Sign In</button>
</div>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: post the code from LoginPage.html

Comment: Please edit your original question with all the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your Console.log with ngAfterViewInit.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('would login user with ', this.user.value, this.password.value);
}
```

Comment: It didnt help.

This is the final code, Please paste the full code as you propose for clarity,

 export class LoginPage {

  @ViewChild('username') user;
  @ViewChild('password') password;

   constructor(private fire: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
   }

   ionViewDidLoad() {
     console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
   }
    //console.log('would login user with ', this.user.value, this.password.value);
  
   signInUser() {
     this.fire.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.value, this.password.value);

  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup to this:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" #username ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" #password></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Use template reference variables - https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-